# Сохранение в пер. объекта, выбранного в зависимости от условий

Tags: ооп, java, netbeans

Требуется решение задачи, очень просто реализуемой на PHP, но непонятно как - на Java (речь о логике).
Мне нужно создать экземпляр одного из 2-х объектов для последующего доступа к его свойствам/методам. Какого именно объекта, - зависит от нек. условий.
Для Java подобное решение:

```
if("Заказчик".equals(uStatus)){
    Customers UserObj = new Customers();
}else{
    if("Диспетчер".equals(uStatus)){
        Bosses UserObj = new Bosses();      
    }
}            
Content = UserObj.getForm();
```

...не работает, т.к. вне условия оно не видит объект UserObj. Выполнять каждый вариант кода внутри всех блоков в зависимости от условия:

```
if("Заказчик".equals(uStatus)){
    Customers UserObj = new Customers();
    Content = UserObj.getForm();
}else{
    if("Диспетчер".equals(uStatus)){
        Bosses UserObj = new Bosses();
        Content = UserObj.getForm();
    }
}
```

...вряд ли рационально. Каким может быть правильное решение с точки зрения концепции Java? Я понимаю, что для тех, кто пишет не ней, вопрос элементарный. Буду очень признателен за разъяснение.

Comment: @falstaf - Вроде работает, спасибо!
Однако ещё вопрос, теоретический: 
Когда просто объявляю переменную типа родительского класса:
    Handlers hdl;
оно мне кричит, что переменная непроинициализирована, хотя далее (внутри условия) я сохраняю в ней экземпляр одного из объектов (Boss / Customer).
Если же пишу, например, Handlers hdl = null; то оно говорит, что всё ОК. Так почему оно видит в первом случае ошибку?

Comment: "Оно" -- это компилятор? Посмотрите на свои if'ы. Если uStatus не равно "Заказчик" или "Диспетчер" -- то значение UserObj не инициализировано.

Comment: Спасибо всем! Просто невероятно, как решение такой элементарнейшей задачи может помочь увидеть действительно важные вещи. И, признаюсь, @DreamChild сделал ценное замечание по поводу ООП.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Вынести метод *getForm* в интерфейс, заимплементировать этот интерфейс классами *Customers* и *Bosses*.
2. Перед началом блока if/else объявить переменную типа объявленного выше интерфейса.
3. В зависимости от каких-то условий присвоить этой переменной ту или иную реализацию интерфейса.
4. После выхода из блока if/else вызвать интерфейсный метод *getForm* и получить результат.

Comment: Мда-уж, решение просто таки брутальное. Попроще нельзя придумать реализацию? Для выполнения простейшего условия сооружать целый интерфейс - неужели это неотъемлемая часть концепции?!

Comment: Можно обойтись без интерфейса, если Customers или Bosses связаны между собой наследованием и метод getForm объявлен в базовом классе.

Comment: И выделять общие части в интерфейсы/базовые классы - неотъемлемая часть концепции ООП вообще, Java/PHP/что-то ещё тут ни при чём.

Comment: >Мда-уж, решение просто таки брутальное

извините, а что вам не нравится? Вам дали очень даже правильный совет - квалифицированные разработчики именно так и делают. А вот эти ваши ветвящиеся if-else с привязкой логики к строковым(!) значениям внутри метода - это тихий ужас, не иначе. То, что PHP с помощью каких-то своих очередных костылей позволяет обходить это - не более, чем особеность отдельно взятого php. В более нормальных языках области видимости переменных разграничиваются жестче.  Так что чем критиковать, лучше примите к сведению

Comment: Я вполне поддерживаю "квалифицированных" разработчиков. Но если задача сиюминутная, данное решение представляется несколько громоздким. Это первое. А второе - логика методов с общим названием getForm() в указанных классах может быть абсолютно разной - в чём смысл выноса его в отдельный интерфейс?
Смысл был в том (ещё раз повторяю) - чтобы получить экземпляр одного из объектов ПО УСЛОВИЮ. Т.е., выполнение метода getForm() было приведено для иллюстрации, основная задача - получить экземпляр объекта со всеми его свойствами и методами.

Comment: Логика разная, семантика же одна - метод возвращает форму. Ну и, опять-таки, меньшая архитектурная связность, что даст свои плоды при развитии кода и написании тестов.

Comment: Представьте себе, что к объекта, который вы возвращаете, нету метода `getForm()` — что тогда? Код с интерфейсом _гарантирует_, что метод есть и будет выполнен. Код на php не гарантирует ничего, отсюда и заслуженная слава php как языка, не требовательного к качеству кода.

Comment: Вы меня удивляете. Рассуждаете вроде бы грамотно, но простых вещей почему-то не понимаете (не сочтите за обиду) Смысл интерфейсов в ООП в том и состоит, чтобы выделять схожее поведение у разных сущностей, в которых это поведение реализуется подчас абсолютно разными способами чтобы потом эти разные сущности использовать, не взирая на их отличия.  Что касается сиюминутной задачи - ну знаете, ООП не для решения сиюминутных задач. И в них его применение может быть излишним

Comment: Я помогаю дочери-студентке разобраться с Java, на которой раньше не писал никогда. Предмет в ВУЗе не то, чтобы плохо преподают - практически никак. Вот в чём источник траблов. Насчёт ООП я и не собираюсь спорить и сам всегда стараюсь использовать подобный подход, но в данном случае времени до сдачи работы крайне мало, к сожалению. Всё делать "как надо" и "красиво" будем учиться летом.
Вот острое где шило. В любом случае - спасибо за стремление помочь!

Comment: Ах вот оно что. Тогда пожалуй вы правы -  все эти ООП-иерархии в институте к сожалению вряд ли оценят. По собственному опыту могу сказать, что во многих институтах подобные вещи преподают чуть лучше чем вообще никак. Так или иначе, если ваша дочь захочет этим заниматься после института, то, скорее всего, многое придется переучивать

Comment: Понятно.
Ну, спасибо всем. Попробую применить подход java-профи и отпишусь о результатах! :)